# set caching from client on javascript files

Tags: javascript, html, caching

I use the google developer tool to test page speed

```
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/
```

Test tells me that I need to set caching on these two files.. How do I do that? There are already caching on the files (30min and 2 hours).. How can I change that from the client?

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false (30 min)
http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can change the caching behavior of these remote servers.

I ended up serving all css and js files from my server rather than CDN/Google. Got 100/100 on page speed with that approach :)